# JQuery Mobile change page with page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery Mobile for a simple mobile web application.

I'm using Single Page Anatomy.

When i'm performing `$.mobile.changePage("sample.html",{transition : pop});`

This seems to load the page  without javascript.

Is there any work-around ? or Is there any new API to load external pages with page transitions also with DOM being loaded properly ?

Comment: What version of jQuery Mobile are you using? What browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the DOM using firebug you'll see that the page is added to the DOM except that when you navigate away it is removed. If you want the page to stay in the DOM you can load the page first  using the [loadPage](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) method

```
$.mobile.loadPage( "sample.html" );
```

And then navigate as you normally would using either a link or `$.mobile.changePage`

If you are talking about the javascript files not being loaded then this is [intentional](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)  and it depends on how the page is loaded) and I don't believe this is new behavior specific to the JQM 1.1.1 release.

Comment: Yes Jack.This loads the page in UI Level.The DOM objects of us.html is not being loaded.

Comment: OK, I'm guessing you mean that it doesn't stay in the DOM, anyway I updated my answer.